# Javascript Only Working in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some really simple javascript implemented into my website, but whenever I visit my site on a different browser other than Chrome, the javascript doesn't do anything. I tried it on my other Mac as well, and the case was the same. So I'm pretty sure it doesn't have anything to do with the computer or browser itself, but the code.

My HTML is the following:

```
<p><a onclick="changeImage('images/diagram.png');" href="#a" class="link">Show Diagram</a></p>
```

Then the javascript:

```
function changeImage(element) {
document.getElementById('diagram').src = element;
}
return false;
```

Comment: Why is the `return false;` outside of the `changeImage` function? Where's the element with id `diagram`?

Comment: Are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I don't think you need to put "return false;"
Remove this line and try again.

Comment: The `return false;` should only stop whatever is after it.

Comment: The `return false` isn't part of the function, it should throw an error when the script loads since a *return* statement is only valid inside a function.

Answer (score -1):

Put return false; into function:

```
function changeImage(element) {
    document.getElementById('diagram').src = element;
    return false;
}
```

There are no problems with posted code, maybe there are bugs in another place.

Comment: That will keep it from scrolling down to the `#a` element, but shouldn't help with the posted problem.

Comment: I see it, but there are no problems in posted code, as I say.

Comment: In that case, it would be better suited as a comment.